# In what cases should a form method be GET and it what cases should it be POST

Tags: html, forms, post, get

When creating an HTML form, in what cases should the form use the GET method and it what cases should the POST method be used. This is a simple question to explain the options of using the two depending on how the form and the information will be handled and how it would help to use one of them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Had this question recently myself.  Best description I found of the differences was here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Don't link to [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: Nice list. Thanks Rick. Also instead of asking not to link, why not write an answer. For what I could see, it has many cases and explains the difference between both.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am noob, but I can say that allways use the `$_GET['']` global when information sent to server is not of any security risk. ex: You can not send a password through the URL, on the other hand, you should always use POST for submitting a sensitive data

Comment: Using POST over GET will not provide additional security other than not showing up in access/referrer logs, as both will be sent in plain-text (unecrypted) unless sent over HTTPS. POST should be used for any form submission where there is a large amount of data being sent such as a textarea field, file upload etc, as GET has length restrictions which will cause it to fail. GET is meant to fetch information without changing the state of any data, POST does however change the state of data like updating a database for example. Please see [RFC 2616](http://tinyurl.com/932c9) for more info on it.