# submit data via URL bar in PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html

I have this very basic form in my html page.

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
    Message: <input type="text" name="message" /> &nbsp; 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"> 
</form>
```

and then stores the data onto my database backend.

id also want to submit data via URL bar, such as this.

`http://localhost/test.php?message=test&submit=send`

but when i try to do above, nothing happens.

how can i achieve such method?

[EDIT]
my post.php

```
<?php
include_once("connect.php");

    if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
        if ($_GET['message'] == "") {
            echo " no input, return";
            exit();
        }
        else {
            $message = $_GET['message'];
            mysql_query("insert into data (message) values ('$message')");
            header ('location:index.php');
            exit ();
        }
    }

    else {
        echo "invalid";
    }

?>
```

Comment: try changing `method="get"`

Comment: ^ Second changing method to "get." Can you show us the code for the "post.php" file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In what cases should a form method be GET and it what cases should it be POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819885/in-what-cases-should-a-form-method-be-get-and-it-what-cases-should-it-be-post)

Comment: Also, the action should be an absolute path (like `/post.php` or `http://localhost/post.php`). It is not strictly necessary but it will prevent problems down the line (such as if you move the form to a sub-directory).

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.  Also, when using a `Location:` header with redirects, you must specify the full URL.  Most browsers will work with something relative, but this does not follow the standards.

Comment: hi yes, i understand the security concerns, im still in the basics of PHP, but i will take note on that. thank you. im sorry if this is already been asked before. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use GET method instead of POST

so your code should be like follow:

```
<form action="post.php" method="GET">
    Message: <input type="text" name="message" /> &nbsp; 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"> 
</form>
```

and in the post.php you can get those Query string by using $_GET['message'] or $_REQUEST['message']

Answer (score 0):

use a form `GET` method. to submit data of a form as a query string.

```
<form action="test.php" method="GET">
```